# Are Schema.org RDFa breadcrumbs available for all search engines?

Tags: google-search, schema.org, bing, breadcrumbs, data-vocabulary.org

I want to implement Schema.org breadcrumbs in RDFa format, following the RDFa guide from here: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs

As this is suggested by Google I can of course consider they support it. But, I see Bing for example has the Data-Vocabulary.org method written in their documentation.

Does anyone know if Bing supports the above mentioned method? Or for that matter if other search engines also support it?